# Repeated call to web service

Tags: android, web-services, timer, handler

I have to call a web service Repeatedly.Time Duration Between Two Calls I minutes.Parameters of web services are based on a spinner value selection.When I select a different value ,now this web service call it self two times within a minute.After Third item selection from spinner it call the service three times within a minute. What I need that web service should be called only one time in a minute.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new FilteredProductionWebAPITask(
                            SpeedometerActivity.this)
                    .execute(branchId);
                    System.out.println("Service:"+counter++ +"Times");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    new FilteredProductionWebAPITask(
                            SpeedometerActivity.this)
                    .cancel(true);
                    alert(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.noData));
                }

            }
        });
    }

};
timer.schedule(task, 0, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: used this removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); but same behavior.

Comment: Please tell me where i have done wrong.

Comment: Where is Spinner code?

Comment: Thanks Every Body for the Help.Trying the Suggestion.Need Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to call the web services after every 1 minute.you need to start the method when you app start like

`mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(CALL_WEB);`

`private static final int    CALL_WEB= 2;`

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            switch (msg.what) {

                case CALL_WEB:
                    Callwebserviceinasync(spinnervalue);


                        sendMessageDelayed(msg, 60*1000);

                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it may be useful

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new FilteredProductionWebAPITask(
                            SpeedometerActivity.this)
                    .execute(branchId);
                    System.out.println("Service:"+counter++ +"Times");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    new FilteredProductionWebAPITask(
                            SpeedometerActivity.this)
                    .cancel(true);
                    alert(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.noData));
                }

            }
        });
    }

};

timer.schedule(task, 0, (60 * 1000)/spinnerValue);
```

Where spinnerValue is 1, 2, 3....

Comment: I exception why you are creating another instance of `new FilteredProductionWebAPITask()` and calling `cancel(true)`?

Comment: Spinner Code--spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int pos, long id) {// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (((TextView) view) != null) {    ((TextView) view).setText(null);}BranchName b = (BranchName) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);     branchId = b.getBrachId(); Here BranchName Is Class Use And BranchId Is an String.